# Returning GMP class with Rcpp

Tags: c++, rcpp, gmp

I'm developing an R library with Rcpp. It wraps a C++ function that uses the GMP library for multiprecision operations. It works fine, the linking it's right and if the R function returns nothing (void), I have check the operation it is done perfectly. Now, my question is: is it possible to return a mpf_class or mpz_class from the C++ function, and bind it in a Rmpfr and bigz object on the R side? Hoping this would not an already asked question

Comment: You need to create conversion functions. This is discussed and explained quite a bit on this site, the mailing list, and else where as the context of adding a new library is somewhat common. Look at vignettes Rcpp-extending and Rcpp-FAQ for a start.

Comment: Ok Dirk, I'll check that documentation again looking for conversion. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the source code of the R library `gmp`? I think you will find your answer there.

Comment: Nop, I've analyzed the C library code, but I'll have a look at the R library too, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I've done it returning from c++ a Rcpp::StringVector, and in the RcppExports.R I'm getting the list returned in the .Call method and converting the items with the gmp::as.bigz() function. It works, the pain is that I've to be careful when executing Rcpp::compileAtributtes() because the file is overwritten.

I've tried defining the wrap function, but it doesn´t work as I expected.